# slick slider - syncing autoplay and active navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I am trying to use the slick Slider to create a slider that allows a user to select the title of the section and see the slide for it but also give the option for it to autoplay.

The stuff works fine. But I need some way to correspond into make it so that when it autoplays, it corresponds to the active navigation and changes it color.

Right now it only show a new color for the active slide title if a user is clicking it. I want it to do so on autoplay also

how would I do that??

Here is the code I have working right now

[Js Bin](http://jsbin.com/nohegaqubu/1/edit?html,js,output)

The only thing I changed is that autoplay option that does not exist on the demo of slick slider

```
 $('.slider-for').slick({
 slidesToShow: 1,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 arrows: false,
 fade: true,
 asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
 autoplay:true

  });
$('.slider-nav').slick({
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,
asNavFor: '.slider-for',
dots: true,
centerMode: true,
focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bpbaz10L/

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,        
    autoplay:true,
    //trigger after the slide appears
    // i is current slide index
    onAfterChange:function(slickSlider,i){
         //remove all active class
         $('.slider-nav .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-active');
         //set active class for current slide
         $('.slider-nav .slick-slide').eq(i).addClass('slick-active');         
     }

});


//set active class to first slide
$('.slider-nav .slick-slide').eq(0).addClass('slick-active');
```

Comment: That worked great.. thanks. 
If you have the time, would  you be able to explain what the role of i is and eq. ? Just so I can learn how to use it efficiently in the future

Comment: onAfterChange return i - the index of current slide. For eq see this [link](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). "_Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index_." When he finds out the current index , then we can know that slide in navigation should be set to active

Comment: For anyone else bumping into this issue + furiously googling for a solution + wondering why `onAfterChange` isn't working: see https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#events

The onAfterChange callback has now been deprecated in favor of the `afterChange` event.

Comment: Cool solution. However with autoplay enabled the active class doesn't change on the nav element. Is this somehow possible to make this working with autoplay as well?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Slick Slider Version: 1.5.5
you will need to call afterChange on().

```js
// function event,slick and index
// version 1.5+ uses slick-current stead of slick-active
$('.slider-for').on('afterChange', function(event,slick,i){
  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-current');
  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide').eq(i).addClass('slick-current');         
});

// remember document ready on this
$('.slider-nav .slick-slide').eq(0).addClass('slick-current');
```

Answer (score 0):

the dm4web answer is perfect if you are showing all the slides you have in your nav slider. If you have more slides that are hidden (say you have 12 slides, but show only 8 in your nav at once), you can do something similar, like

```
$('.slider-nav').on('afterChange', function(){

  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide').removeClass('current');
  $('.slider-nav .slick-active:first').addClass('current');
});

//set active class to first slide
$('.slider-nav .slick-active:first').addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function _Slider(){
        $('#hm-slider ul').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            arrows:false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 5000,
            fade: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            asNavFor: '#slider-dots',
        }); 
        $('#slider-dots').slick({
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            asNavFor: '#hm-slider ul',
            dots: false,
            centerMode: false,
            focusOnSelect: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            centerMode: true,
            useCSS:true
        });

        //set active class to first slide
        $('#slider-dots .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-active');
        $('#slider-dots .slick-slide').eq(0).addClass('slick-active');
        $('#hm-slider ul').on({
            beforeChange: function(event, slick, current_slide_index, next_slide_index) {
                //remove all active class
                $('#slider-dots .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-active');
                //set active class for current slide
                $('#slider-dots .slick-slide[data-slick-index='+next_slide_index+']').addClass('slick-active');
            }
        });

    }
```