# Ken Wheeler Slick Slider 1.4 - .slick-active is activating all visible in the asNavFor, not the one showing

Tags: jquery

When a user clicks on the thumbs OR the main slider to advance, you'd think that the `.slick-active` would indicate in the thumbs the slide mirrored in the main slider, but instead all the thumbs are set to `.slick-active`. I'm using version 1.4 of this script.

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/mevaga/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.portfolio-thumb-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.portfolio-item-slider',
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        focusOnSelect: true
    });


    $('.portfolio-item-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        asNavFor: '.portfolio-thumb-slider'
    });


});
```

[image]

What have I tried: [slick slider - syncing autoplay and active navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260225/slick-slider-syncing-autoplay-and-active-navigation) -- This does not work. It used to work in the older version of this script BUT only initially, once the slide advances it didn't work.

Comment: The `.slick-active` class is given to all the current visible thumbs as far as I understand it. So in your case to 4 thumbs instead of just one like you desire it.

Comment: Yes, that is what happens but logically, the way that flexslider, owlslider (now abandoned) and others work, the one showing and the thumb are active, the rest are not, which is what is expected. It's really strange the way it is by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I fiddeled around a bit and this seems to be working:

```
$('.portfolio-thumb-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  //remove all active class
  $('.portfolio-thumb-slider .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-active1');
  //set active class for current slide
     $('.portfolio-thumb-slider .slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned)').eq(currentSlide).addClass('slick-active1');
```

`.slick-active1` is always given to the current active thumb.

I agree with you that it is strange that this slider hasn't this feature by itself.

**[Final working example](https://jsbin.com/yifivi/1/edit?css,js,output)**

Comment: That totally rocks! Thank you so much!

Comment: The other annoying thing that this script does is that onload the layout is screwed up unless you use window load instead of doc ready, but instead I just change the opacity on ready. Here's the better version: https://jsbin.com/dokina/1/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Really? I used the slick slider in one of my projects before and didn't experience anything like that.. But who knows, nothing is impossible in web development.. ;) Its a nice solution you found for it.

Comment: Doesnt work with "infinite: false" option. Helps would be appreciated :)